# Captains' reiatsu levels after donating to Ichigo

Tags: bleach

When the captains and vice captains gave their powers in Urahara's sword to restore Ichigo's powers, did they permanently lose part of their powers?

Comment: I think not. I think it worked the same way as blood transfusion. Sure, they got weakened from giving out reiatsu, but it will recover over time.

Comment: Is there any canon evidence to support this?

Answer (score 2):

Nope. I believe it's the same case as Rukia. Even though she borrowed her powers to Ichigo at the start of the series and couldn't recover her powers while in the Human World, this was mostly because of Urahara's Special Gigai. By the time she returned to Soul Society, she eventually got all of her powers back.